# sql - Get the Minimum Value of 2 subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, min

I have a query which has 5 subqueries. I need it to have only 4 subqueries, since two of them are supposed to be only one result. The problem is I don't know how to maintain the query structure and get the MIN value of 2 of those subqueries. This is my query:

```
Select Artigo, Descricao, sum(Stock) as Stock, Sum(QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes) as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, Sum(Stock) - Sum(QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes) As StockTotal
From (

    Select A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, sum(AA.StkActual) as Stock, 0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Artigo Stock' As Id
    From Artigo A1
        Inner Join ArtigoArmazem AA On AA.Artigo = A1.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A1','A5','A7','A8','A9'))
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    Group By A1.Artigo, A1.Descricao

    Union

    Select A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, 0 as Stock, Sum(LD.Quantidade - LDS.QuantTrans) as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Artigo Encomenda' As Id
    From Artigo A1
        Inner Join LinhasDoc LD On LD.Artigo = A1.Artigo And Year(LD.Data) >= 2018 And LD.Quantidade Is Not Null And LD.Quantidade > 0
        Inner Join LinhasDocStatus LDS On LDS.IdLinhasDoc = LD.Id  And LDS.Fechado = 0 And LDS.Quantidade > LDS.QuantTrans
        Inner Join CabecDocStatus CDS On CDS.IdCabecDoc = LD.IdCabecDoc And CDS.Fechado = 0 And CDS.Estado = 'P'
        Inner Join CabecDoc CD On CD.Id = LD.IdCabecDoc And CD.TipoDoc = 'NET' And CD.Serie = 'SITE'
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    Group By A1.Artigo, A1.Descricao

    Union

    select
        A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, FLOOR(MIN(CASE WHEN A2.familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / 2 ELSE AA.StkActual END)) as Stock, 0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Componente Stock' As Id
    from
        Artigo A1
        join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (37,38,39,45))
        join ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A7'))
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    group by
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao

    Union

    select
        A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, (coalesce(MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A7' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ), MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A8' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ), MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A9' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ))) as Stock, 0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Componente Stock' As Id
    from
        Artigo A1
        join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (98))
        join ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A7', 'A8', 'A9'))
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    group by
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao

    Union

    Select A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, 0 as Stock, Sum(LD.Quantidade - LDS.QuantTrans) as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Componente Encomenda' As Id
    From Artigo A1
        Inner Join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        Inner Join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (37,38,39,45,98))
        Inner Join LinhasDoc LD On LD.Artigo = A2.Artigo And Year(LD.Data) >= 2018 And LD.Quantidade Is Not Null And LD.Quantidade > 0
        Inner Join LinhasDocStatus LDS On LDS.IdLinhasDoc = LD.Id  And LDS.Fechado = 0 And LDS.Quantidade > LDS.QuantTrans
        Inner Join CabecDocStatus CDS On CDS.IdCabecDoc = LD.IdCabecDoc And CDS.Fechado = 0 And CDS.Estado = 'P' And LDS.IdLinhasDoc Is Not Null 
        Inner Join CabecDoc CD On CD.Id = LD.IdCabecDoc And CD.TipoDoc = 'NET' And CD.Serie = 'SITE' And CDS.IdCabecDoc Is Not Null
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    Group By A1.Artigo, A1.Descricao

) As Result
Group by Artigo, Descricao
order by Descricao
```

And I need to get the minimum value of the 3rd and 4th subqueries instead of adding both of them to the SUM(Stock) of the main query. How can I achieve that? I need to maintain the query structure..
I need the MIN from the Result of those queries (3rd and 4th):

```
select
        A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, FLOOR(MIN(CASE WHEN A2.familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / 2 ELSE AA.StkActual END)) as Stock, 0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Componente Stock' As Id
    from
        Artigo A1
        join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (37,38,39,45))
        join ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A7'))
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    group by
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao

    Union

    select
        A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, (coalesce(MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A7' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ), MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A8' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ), MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A9' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ))) as Stock, 0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Componente Stock' As Id
    from
        Artigo A1
        join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (98))
        join ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A7', 'A8', 'A9'))
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    group by
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao
```

Comment: Just union them together first, find the minimum, and then union the result with the other subqueries.

Comment: @EzLo How? I've been trying to do that for days but It seems impossible. I can't change the query structure as It needs to calculate all the stocks from "diferrent angles".. I suck at sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider turning subqueries into multiple [CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), then in `UNION` query add columns for *Stock3* and *Stock4* based on corresponding *Stock* to aggregate for `MIN` values, filling in `NULL`s for other queries:

```
WITH first_agg AS (
    SELECT A1.Artigo AS Artigo, A1.Descricao AS Descricao, 
          SUM(AA.StkActual) AS Stock, 
          0 AS QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 
          'Artigo Stock' AS Id
    FROM Artigo A1
    INNER JOIN ArtigoArmazem AA 
        ON AA.Artigo = A1.Artigo 
        AND (AA.Armazem IN ('A1','A5','A7','A8','A9'))
        AND A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    GROUP BY A1.Artigo, A1.Descricao
), 

second_agg AS (
    SELECT A1.Artigo AS Artigo, A1.Descricao AS Descricao, 
           0 AS Stock, 
           SUM(LD.Quantidade - LDS.QuantTrans) AS QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 
           'Artigo Encomenda' AS Id
    FROM Artigo A1
        INNER JOIN LinhasDoc LD 
             ON LD.Artigo = A1.Artigo AND Year(LD.Data) >= 2018 
             AND LD.Quantidade Is Not Null AND LD.Quantidade > 0
        INNER JOIN LinhasDocStatus LDS 
             ON LDS.IdLinhasDoc = LD.Id  
             AND LDS.Fechado = 0 AND LDS.Quantidade > LDS.QuantTrans
        INNER JOIN CabecDocStatus CDS 
             ON CDS.IdCabecDoc = LD.IdCabecDoc 
             AND CDS.Fechado = 0 AND CDS.Estado = 'P'
        INNER JOIN CabecDoc CD 
             ON CD.Id = LD.IdCabecDoc 
             AND CD.TipoDoc = 'NET' AND CD.Serie = 'SITE'
        AND A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    GROUP BY A1.Artigo, A1.Descricao
),

third_agg AS (    
    SELECT
        A1.Artigo AS Artigo, A1.Descricao AS Descricao, 
        FLOOR(MIN(CASE 
                       WHEN A2.familia = 39 
                       THEN AA.StkActual / 2 
                       ELSE AA.StkActual 
                  END)) AS Stock, 
        0 AS QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 
        'Componente Stock' AS Id
    FROM
        Artigo A1
        INNER JOIN ComponentesArtigos CA 
              ON CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        INNER JOIN Artigo A2 
              ON A2.Artigo = CA.Componente AND (A2.Familia IN (37,38,39,45))
        INNER JOIN ArtigoArmazem AA 
              ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo AND (AA.Armazem IN ('A7'))
        AND A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    GROUP BY
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao
),

fourth_agg AS (
    SELECT A1.Artigo AS Artigo, A1.Descricao AS Descricao, 
            (COALESCE(MIN(
                CASE
                    WHEN AA.Armazem = 'A7' 
                    THEN CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                    ELSE NULL
                END
            ), MIN(
                CASE
                    WHEN AA.Armazem = 'A8' 
                    THEN CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                    ELSE NULL
                END
            ), MIN(
                CASE
                    WHEN AA.Armazem = 'A9' 
                    THEN CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                    ELSE NULL
                END
            ))) AS Stock, 
            0 AS QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 
            'Componente Stock' AS Id
    FROM
        Artigo A1
        INNER JOIN ComponentesArtigos CA 
              ON CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        INNER JOIN Artigo A2 
              ON A2.Artigo = CA.Componente AND (A2.Familia IN (98))
        INNER JOIN ArtigoArmazem AA 
              ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo AND (AA.Armazem IN ('A7', 'A8', 'A9'))
              AND A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    GROUP BY
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao
),

fifth_agg AS (
    SELECT A1.Artigo AS Artigo, A1.Descricao AS Descricao, 
           0 AS Stock, 
           SUM(LD.Quantidade - LDS.QuantTrans) AS QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 
           'Componente Encomenda' AS Id
    FROM Artigo A1
        INNER JOIN ComponentesArtigos CA 
              ON CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        INNER JOIN Artigo A2 
              ON A2.Artigo = CA.Componente AND (A2.Familia IN (37,38,39,45,98))
        INNER JOIN LinhasDoc LD 
              ON LD.Artigo = A2.Artigo AND Year(LD.Data) >= 2018 
              AND LD.Quantidade Is Not Null AND LD.Quantidade > 0
        INNER JOIN LinhasDocStatus LDS 
              ON LDS.IdLinhasDoc = LD.Id  
              AND LDS.Fechado = 0 AND LDS.Quantidade > LDS.QuantTrans
        INNER JOIN CabecDocStatus CDS 
              ON CDS.IdCabecDoc = LD.IdCabecDoc AND CDS.Fechado = 0 
              AND CDS.Estado = 'P' AND LDS.IdLinhasDoc Is Not Null 
        INNER JOIN CabecDoc CD 
              ON CD.Id = LD.IdCabecDoc AND CD.TipoDoc = 'NET' 
              AND CD.Serie = 'SITE' AND CDS.IdCabecDoc Is Not Null
        AND A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    GROUP BY A1.Artigo, A1.Descricao
)


SELECT Artigo, Descricao, 
       SUM(Stock) AS Stock, 
       SUM(QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes) AS QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 
       SUM(Stock) - SUM(QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes) AS StockTotal,
       MIN(Stock3) AS MIN_Stock3,
       MIN(Stock4) AS Min_Stock4

FROM (    
       SELECT Artigo, Descricao, Stock, NULL AS Stock3, NULL AS Stock4, 
              QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, ID 
       FROM first_agg

       UNION 

       SELECT Artigo, Descricao, Stock, NULL AS Stock3, NULL AS Stock4, 
              QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, ID 
       FROM second_agg

       UNION

       SELECT Artigo, Descricao, Stock, Stock AS Stock3, NULL AS Stock4, 
              QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, ID 
       FROM third_agg

       UNION

       SELECT Artigo, Descricao, Stock, NULL AS Stock3, Stock AS Stock4, 
              QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, ID 
       FROM fourth_agg

       UNION

       SELECT Artigo, Descricao, Stock, NULL AS Stock3, NULL AS Stock4, 
              QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, ID 
       FROM fifth_agg      

) AS Result
GROUP BY Artigo, Descricao
ORDER BY Descricao
```

Comment: Didn't know about those CTE's. Thanks Parfait, you didn't give me exactly what I need, but I finally got the solution thanks to your help <3

Comment: Sounds good! Yes, CTEs allow you to define a resultset once and reuse anywhere even inside other CTEs compared to subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

Use the below query for your 3rd and 4th query.

```
SELECT Artigo ,Descricao , Stock , QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes , Id
FROM
(
SELECT Artigo ,Descricao , Stock , QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes , Id ,    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Stock ASC) RN
FROM
(
select
        A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, FLOOR(MIN(CASE WHEN A2.familia = 39 THEN AA.StkActual / 2 ELSE AA.StkActual END)) as Stock, 0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Componente Stock' As Id
    from
        Artigo A1
        join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (37,38,39,45))
        join ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A7'))
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    group by
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao

    Union

    select
        A1.Artigo as Artigo, A1.Descricao as Descricao, (coalesce(MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A7' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ), MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A8' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ), MIN(
            CASE
                when AA.Armazem = 'A9' then 
                    CASE WHEN A2.Familia = 98 THEN AA.StkActual END
                else
                    null
            end
        ))) as Stock, 0 as QuantidadeEmEncomendasPendentes, 'Componente Stock' As Id
    from
        Artigo A1
        join ComponentesArtigos CA On CA.ArtigoComposto = A1.Artigo
        join Artigo A2 On A2.Artigo = CA.Componente And (A2.Familia IN (98))
        join ArtigoArmazem AA ON AA.Artigo = A2.Artigo And (AA.Armazem IN ('A7', 'A8', 'A9'))
        and A1.CDU_DisponivelOnline = 1
    group by
        A1.Artigo,
        A1.Descricao
sql sql-server subquery min
)
)
WHERE RN = 1
```

You can check below link for more details on `ROW_NUMBER()`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: couldn't make it work.. I just need a query to get the MIN value of those 2 subqueries together, but it needs to be on that main query